# Tracking multiple presses via libgdx and android

Tags: java, android, libgdx, multi-touch

Hi I've got an issue with an app I'm making for a "virtual drum-kit" I'm not to fantastic with libgdx I will be honest, I was taught "what I needed to know" by somebody who I am no longer in contact with.

The app is all up and running great however when I use it on an android device I can not hit two drums/cymbals at the same time it just repeats the sound of the drum I was already pressing, I think I am probably not using the best method to track presses but as said I am fairly unfamiliar with libgdx, if I paste my code it would be great to get some help or advice off you guys!

Here is the class that runs my virtual drum:

```
package gamebulk.drumkit;

import java.util.Random;

import gamebulk.drumkit.DrumKit.DialogListener;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GLCommon;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;

public class DrumScreen implements Screen, ApplicationListener {

Game game;

OrthographicCamera guiCam;
SpriteBatch batcher;
Rectangle snareBounds;
Rectangle hihatBounds;
Rectangle crashBounds;
Rectangle rideBounds;
Rectangle bassBounds;
Rectangle hitBounds;
Rectangle lowtBounds;
Rectangle floortBounds;
Rectangle exitBounds;
Vector3 touchPoint;
DialogListener callback;

float time = 0;

public final Random rand;

public DrumScreen (Game game, DialogListener callback) {
    this.game = game;

    guiCam = new OrthographicCamera(800, 480);
    guiCam.position.set(800 / 2, 480 / 2, 0);
    batcher = new SpriteBatch();
    snareBounds = new Rectangle (180, 150, 147, 80);
    hihatBounds = new Rectangle (28, 184, 160, 90);
    crashBounds = new Rectangle(36, 310, 246, 160);     
    rideBounds = new Rectangle (550, 250, 222, 140);
    bassBounds = new Rectangle (278, 38, 250, 211);
    hitBounds = new Rectangle (256, 242, 132, 96);
    lowtBounds = new Rectangle (410, 240, 130, 92);
    floortBounds = new Rectangle (494, 128, 178, 118);
    exitBounds = new Rectangle (704, 384, 64, 64);
    touchPoint = new Vector3();
    this.callback = callback;
    Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
    rand = new Random ();

}

public void update (float deltaTime) {

    handleInput(deltaTime);

    if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
        guiCam.unproject(touchPoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));


        if (OverlapTester.pointInRectangle(snareBounds, touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
            if (rand.nextFloat() < 0.5){
                Assets.playSound(Assets.snare1sound);}
            else{
                Assets.playSound(Assets.snare2sound);
            }
        }
        if (OverlapTester.pointInRectangle(hihatBounds, touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
            if (rand.nextFloat() < 0.5){
                Assets.playSound(Assets.hihat1sound);}
            else{
                Assets.playSound(Assets.hihat2sound);
            }
        }               
        if (OverlapTester.pointInRectangle(crashBounds, touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
            if (rand.nextFloat() < 0.5){
                Assets.playSound(Assets.crash1sound);}
            else{
                Assets.playSound(Assets.crash1sound);
            }
        }   
        if (OverlapTester.pointInRectangle(rideBounds, touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
            if (rand.nextFloat() < 0.5){
                Assets.playSound(Assets.ride1sound);}
            else{
                Assets.playSound(Assets.ride2sound);
            }
        }   
        if (OverlapTester.pointInRectangle(bassBounds, touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
            if (rand.nextFloat() < 0.5){
                Assets.playSound(Assets.bass1sound);}
            else{
                Assets.playSound(Assets.bass2sound);
            }
        }   
        if (OverlapTester.pointInRectangle(hitBounds, touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
            Assets.playSound(Assets.hitom1sound);
        }   
        if (OverlapTester.pointInRectangle(lowtBounds, touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
            Assets.playSound(Assets.lowtom1sound);
        }   
        if (OverlapTester.pointInRectangle(floortBounds, touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
            Assets.playSound(Assets.floortom1sound);
        }   

        if (OverlapTester.pointInRectangle(exitBounds, touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
            if (callback != null){
                callback.showOfferwall2();} 
                Gdx.app.exit();
        }
    }
}

private void handleInput(float delta) {  

time += delta;
if (time > 0.5) {
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.BACK)) {                  
callback.showOfferwall2();
Gdx.app.exit();}
}       
}

public void draw (float delta) {
GLCommon gl = Gdx.gl;
time += delta;
gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
guiCam.update();
batcher.setProjectionMatrix(guiCam.combined);

batcher.enableBlending();
batcher.begin();
batcher.draw(Assets.drumbackground, 0, 0);

batcher.draw(Assets.exitbutton, 704, 384);

batcher.end();      

}

@Override
public void render (float delta) {
update(delta);
draw(delta);
}

@Override
public void resize (int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void show () {
}

@Override
public void hide () {
}

@Override
public void resume () {
}

@Override
public void dispose () {
}

@Override
public void pause() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void create() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void render() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Any help relating to this would be fantastic thanks in advance.

Comment: First result on Google:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876877/how-to-track-multiple-touch-events-in-libgdx

Answer (score 0):

The Libgdx Input `getX()` method returns the x coordinate for the first touch point (aka the first finger).  The `justTouched()` method returns true for each new touch event (for any finger).

So your current code is running every time any touch-down event triggers on the screen.  But then it only looks at the coordinates of the first finger's touch point.

Libgdx does not have a `justTouched()` method for any other pointer (it does have `getX(int)` and `getY(int)` method for checking the coordinates of other pointers).  So, you'll probably want to do your own just-touched check (assuming you don't want to switch from input polling to event-based inputs).

First, decide how many fingers you want to support on the screen.  Its cheap to support lots, so try 40.  Add a new class variable:

```
private static final int maxFingers = 40;
```

Add a new instance variable for the just-touched check:

```
boolean sawTouch[maxFingers];
```

and initialize it in your constructor:

```
sawTouch = new boolean[40];
```

Now, you just check every pointer to see if been touched, and if so where, and then run your sounds:

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxFingers; i++) {
   if (Gdx.input.isTouched(i)) {
      if (!sawTouch[i]) {
         sawTouch[i] = true;  // Mark this finger as "seen" for future checks

         // Figure out where the i'th touch was
         guiCam.unproject(touchPoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(i), Gdx.input.getY(i), 0));

         // XXX put all the code that does OverlapTester.calls here (or put that in a separate function and call it here) 
      }
      // else already saw the touch ..
   } else {
      sawTouch[i] = false; // Finger is gone, any future touch is "new"
   }
}
```

Or something approaching that.  I haven't tried compiling this code, so it might have typos, but hopefully it gets the idea across.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, I'm having some trouble trying to get this implemented, wherever I place the boolean I'm getting an error: Syntax error on token "maxFingers", delete this token

I've tried it in a few different places and can't figure it out I've also tried looking at the libgdx tutorial for handling input but still not really getting it!

Comment: The `maxFingers` declaration should go at "class scope" in your code (i.e., next to the line `public final Random rand;` that declares `rand`).  (Same with the declaration of `sawTouch`.)