# Libgdx multiTouch not working

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, 2d-games

I'm developing a game , and I'm using Libgdx Library in this game. It will work on Android and must play with two players on one screen. But I can't get the another player inputs. I can play with bottom or top player, but not both.

This is the get input codes:

```
public class PlayStateInput implements InputProcessor {

private PlayState playState;
private Vector2 touchPos;
private Vector2 bodyCord;


public PlayStateInput(PlayState playState){

    this.playState = playState;
    touchPos = new Vector2();
    bodyCord = new Vector2();

    touchPos.x=Gdx.input.getX();
    touchPos.y=Gdx.input.getY();
    bodyCord.x=playState.getGameWorld().getPaddle().getBody().getPosition().x;
    bodyCord.y=playState.getGameWorld().getPaddle().getBody().getPosition().y;

}

@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

    if(playState.getGameWorld().getPuck().getCircleRect().contains(screenX,screenY)){

        System.out.println("collision");
    }

    if(screenY > Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 && (pointer <= 2)){
        playState.getGameWorld().getPaddle2().setBottomPaddle(true);

    }

    if(screenY < Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 && (pointer <= 2)){
        playState.getGameWorld().getPaddle().setTopPaddle(true);
    }

    return false;
}
```

And the use this inputs here:

```
public class Paddle implements GameObject {


private World world;
private Body body;
private Body body2;
private BodyDef bodyDef;
private BodyDef bodyDef2;
private Fixture fixture;
private Fixture fixture2;
private FixtureDef fixtureDef;
private FixtureDef fixtureDef2;


private Circle circleRect;
private Circle circleRect2;
boolean TopPaddle = false;
boolean BottomPaddle = false;

private float PPM=100f;
private float power=100f;

private Vector2 touchPos;

private Sprite sprite;

String koordinatlar;


public Paddle(World world){


    this.world = world;

    bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.set((Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2)/PPM,(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/3)/PPM);

    body = world.createBody(bodyDef);



    fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 1.0f;
    fixtureDef.restitution=0.3f;


    CircleShape circleShape = new CircleShape();
    circleShape.setRadius((Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/16)/PPM);
    fixtureDef.shape = circleShape;

    fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);

    circleRect = new Circle(body.getPosition().x,body.getPosition().y,(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/16));

    Sprite.split(ImageLoader.playButtonRegion.getTexture(),20,20);



    sprite = new Sprite(ImageLoader.paddle);
    sprite.setSize((Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/8),(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/8));
    sprite.setPosition((Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2)-30f,(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/3)-30f);


    touchPos = new Vector2();

}

@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {


    sprite.draw(sb);
    sprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x*PPM-30f,body.getPosition().y*PPM-30f);
}

@Override
public void update(float delta) {

    touchPos.x=Gdx.input.getX()/PPM;
    touchPos.y=Gdx.input.getY()/PPM;

    System.out.println(touchPos);


    if (TopPaddle) {

        body.setLinearVelocity(power*(touchPos.x-body.getPosition().x),power*(touchPos.y-body.getPosition().y));
        body.setAngularVelocity(0.0f);


        if(Gdx.input.getY()>Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2){

            body.setLinearVelocity(0f,0f);
        }
        //System.out.println(Gdx.input.getX()+" "+Gdx.input.getY());
    }
```

}

I hope, I made myself clear.

Comment: To properly support multi touch, you need to implement an InputListener and track pointer indices to distinguish between down fingers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see your problem, you are relying on the fact that only one input is being taken at a time. As a result, you will be ignoring one of the two players if both are giving input simultaneously.

There are multiple ways to go about solving your multi-touch input problem but I'll go about explaining a simple technique - modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876877/how-to-track-multiple-touch-events-in-libgdx).

To allow both players to take in input you will need two variables - I'll call them `topTouchPos` and `bottomTouchPos`. Each of these will be a `Vector2` like your current `touchPos` and they will be calculated as follows (inside your `update` method):

```
//Initialise both vectors to vectors that can't be touched (negative)
Vector2 topTouchPos = new Vector2(-1,-1), bottomTouchPos = new Vector2(-1,-1);

//Two people can have up to 20 fingers (most touchscreen devices will have a lower limit anyway)
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    //Check if this finger ID is touched
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched(i)) {
        //Classify it as either the top or bottom player
        bool bottom = Gdx.input.getY(i) > Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2;
        if (bottom) bottomTouchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(i), Gdx.input.getY(i));
        else topTouchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(i), Gdx.input.getY(i));
    }
}
```

When you get into your main game code you will have to check for both players. If either `topTouchPos` or `bottomTouchPos` are not negative then use their touch values for their respective players.

Hope this helps (I haven't tested any code so beware of any typos).

Comment: I think my game is aware of the second input but it is not able to change x  and y coordinates of the other paddle for some reason.